Any usage for using hyphen and slash in the same word combination?
I saw "move-in/out" and "setup/tear down" in an OTIS manual, and wonder which punctuation shall override the other in such case.
In the 1st combination, it's clearly the shortened form of "move-in" and "move-out", with the 2nd move eliminated, so the hyphen here seems to be on the upper level of the slash.
In the 2nd combination, it's the grouping of "setup" and "tear down" (given that there is no hyphen between tear and down, it's possible to be interpreted as "setup down" and "tear down" shortened, which is obviously not the meaning intended in the manual). So is it grammatically feasible to add a hyphen and change it into "setup/tear-down"? If in such case, the slash would override the hyphen.
So, are there any specified usage on this matter? Or such combined use is simply not accepted?

Is there a particular reason you need a slash? APA says "Do not use a slash when a phrase would be clearer" (like "setup or tear down") and that seems good advice here. See also for instance Australian government style guide for more alternatives. That said, using "teardown" as one word is possible -  though even then, "setup/teardown" may not be recommended.

Please show the intended usage. In the second usage "setup/tear down" is unclear because of the space in the alternative, which might suggest "setup down" or "tear down". Using "setup/destroy" would be clearer.

Sorry; too many problems:
There is no 'shortened' form of 'move-in/out' merely your newly-made form, which being new, needs justifying.
How would you relate that to the unequal pair 'setup/tear down'?
Could you rephrase the whole thing so either
'move-in/out' or 'setup/tear down' at least matched within themselves, let alone the other pair, or did you mean something different?

The term 'move-in' is a noun in this context. It is one word. So, the corresponding opposite term should be the one-word noun 'move-out', and the phrase should be written as 'move-in/move-out'.
Similarly, 'setup' and 'tear down' are nouns in this context. And 'teardown' -- written as one word in noun form -- accepted for use by Cambridge and Merriam Webster.

Some compound nouns are spelled in a variety of ways, for instance ink well/ink-well/inkwell and particle board/particle-board/particleboard. [Using traditional analysis which allows open compounds as single lexemes.]
